# How can I read an image from a URL in Android?

Tags: android

I want to read an image from a this URL [photo](http://184.173.7.132/RealAds_Images/Apartment%20for%20sale,%20Sheikh%20Zayed%20_%201.jpg)

and I'm using the following code

```
 public static Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
{
    Bitmap bitmap=null;
    InputStream in=null;
    try {
        in=networking.OpenHttpConnection("http://izwaj.com/"+URL);
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize=8;

        bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
        in.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return bitmap;
}

 public class Networking {
public InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)

        throws IOException
        {
    InputStream in=null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url=new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn=url.openConnection();

    if(!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
    {
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");
    }

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpconn=(HttpURLConnection)conn;
        httpconn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpconn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpconn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpconn.connect();
        response=httpconn.getResponseCode();
        if(response==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
        {
            in=httpconn.getInputStream();
        }
    }



    catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;

        }
```

The bitmap always returned to me null.. I used also other functions found on the internet. all returned the bitmap as null value :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this function  it may help you.

```
public Bitmap convertImage(String url)
     {

        URL aURL = null;
        try 
       {
        final String imageUrl =url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
        Log.e("Image Url",imageUrl);
        aURL = new URL(imageUrl);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); 
        //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is); 
        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new PatchInputStream(bis)); 
        if(bm==null)
        {}
        else
       Bitmap bit=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,72, 72, true);//mention size here

        return bit;

       } 


        catch (IOException e) 
        {
           Log.e("error in bitmap",e.getMessage());
          return null;
       }


      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would check the %20 spacing on the picture

```
http://184.173.7.132/RealAds_Images/Apartment%20for%20sale,%20Sheikh%20Zayed%20_%201.jpg
```

To me the %20 will not render a space so ensure this is noted in your code

if you change the file to apartmentforsalesheikhzayed20201.jpg or something like as a test apartment.jpg it will work.

Personally instead of using spaces in your image names i would use an underscore between the spaces so no other code is needed try_renaming_your_photo_to_this.jpg   :)

Comment: Good point on the underscore usage. URI class in android also has stuff for safely encoding and decoding URL/URI. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html#encode%28java.lang.String%29